What does "all cohorts" refer to in the context of Parent Plus Loan metrics?
I'm looking for help with understanding two metrics from CollegeScoreCard Institutions level data dictionary: "Number of students associated with outstanding Parent PLUS Loan balances" and "Total outstanding Parent PLUS Loan balance." The data dictionary states that these are measured across "all cohorts," but doesn't provide further clarification on what "all cohorts" means.
I see two possible interpretations. For example, the "2021 Number of students associated with outstanding Parent PLUS Loan balances" could either refer to:

The number of undergraduate students enrolled in 2020-2021 who have a Parent PLUS Loan
The number of undergraduate students enrolled before 2021 who still have an outstanding Parent PLUS Loan, so it is cumulative count/estimate of EVERYBODY who has outstanding Loan.

Could anyone clarify which interpretation is correct?
